# How do I jump to the next or previous word with CTRL + arrow keys in a console?

Tags: linux, terminal, keyboard-shortcuts

In terminal emulation applications, pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>Left</kbd> / <kbd>Right</kbd> arrows jumps from one word to the previous or next one. Is it possible to have the same functionality in a Linux console, whether it is in text or in framebuffer modes?

In my configuration, the <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + arrow keys are transformed into escaped character sequences and not interpreted.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is possible if and only if the terminal sends different escape sequences for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd> vs <kbd>Left</kbd>. This is not the case by default on the Linux console (at least on my machine). You can make it so by modifying the keymap. The exact file to modify may depend on your distribution; on Debian lenny, the file to modify is `/etc/console/boottime.kmap.gz`. You need lines like

```
control keycode 105 = F100
string F100 = "\033O5D"
control keycode 106 = F101
string F101 = "\033O5C"
```

You might as well choose the same escape sequences as your X terminal emulator. To find out what the control sequence is, type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd> in a shell; this inserts (on my machine) `^[O5D` where `^[` is an escape character. In the keymap file, `\033` represents an escape character.

Configuring the application in the terminal to decode the escape sequence is a separate problem, .

Comment: you are only explaining how you got the `"\033O5D"` code, but completely omitting where you got the `keycode 105` and `F100` codes from. Besides, I get `^[[1;5B` and `^[[1;5A` for ctrl+Down and Ctrl+Up. How should I handle the `1;` part?

Comment: @MartinVegter Check the existing file for keycodes, or use the `showkey` program. The `1;` part isn't different from the rest: `"\033[1;5B"` and so on.

Comment: OK the `keycode 105` can be found using `showkey`.  But where did you get the `F100` ?

Comment: @MartinVegter Pick one that isn't already in use. A different one per keychord (I just fixed a typo in my answer).

Answer (score 31):

Emacs-style shortcuts <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>f</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>b</kbd> work by default with all [readline](http://www.gnu.org/software/readline/)-powered command line programs, like shells.

Answer (score 4):

This is not with control + arrows, but I can type <kbd>Esc</kbd> <kbd>B</kbd>
to go back a word and <kbd>Esc</kbd> <kbd>F</kbd> to go forward a word in my Mac Terminal.

Answer (score 3):

I use `zsh`, therefore I can enable this behaviour by editing the `.zshrc` file

The following lines have to be added:

```bash
# Enable Ctrl+arrow key bindings for word jumping
bindkey '^[[1;5C' forward-word     # Ctrl+right arrow
bindkey '^[[1;5D' backward-word    # Ctrl+left arrow
```

I hope this helps at least the `zsh`-users.

Answer (score 2):

You can set vim as your command line editor and then hit ESC and jump around vim style (forward, back, end, $, 0, etc)

Answer (score 0):

On mac terminal option-left/right works for me, you can also edit it in the terminal preferences>Keyboard.

Answer (score -1):

I had this issue on Debian with an empty `~/.inputrc` file. Fixed the problem by removing this file.